# Question about dimensions when processing lists with a multi layer perceptron

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch

I'm quite new to PyTorch and I'm trying to build a net that is composed only of linear layers that will get a list of objects as input and output some score (which is a scalar) for each object. I'm wondering if my input tensor's dimensions should be `(batch_size, list_size, object_size)` or should I flatten each list and get `(batch_size, list_size*object_size)`? According to my understanding, in the first option I will have an output dimension of `(batch_size, list_size, 1)` and in the second `(batch_size, list_size)`, does it matter? I read the documentation but it still wasn't very clear to me.

[image]

Comment: Questions about how a certain library, function, etc. works, or, in general, programming questions are off-topic here. See https://ai.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic for more details. I will migrate this question to Stack Overflow.

Comment: It doesn't matter, you can choose whatever you want for input and output dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do the classification for each object in your input, you should keep the objects separate from each other; i.e., your input should be in the shape of `(batch_size, list_size, object_size)`. Then considering the number of classes you got (let's say `m` classes), the linear layer would transform the input to the shape of `(batch_size, list_size, m)`. In this case, you will have `m` scores for each object which can be utilized to predict the class label.

But question arises now; why do we flatten in neural networks at all? The answer is simple: because you want to couple the whole information (in your specific case, the information pieces are the objects) within a batch to see if they somehow affect each other, and if that's the case, to examine whether your network is able to learn these features/patterns. In practice, considering the nature of your problem and the data you are working with, if different objects really relate to each other, then your network will be able to learn those.

Comment: The classification of each object in each list depends on the other objects in the list. If I use the first option - (batch_size, list_size, object_size) - then the classification of each object in the list will not be affected by other objects in the list?

Comment: It all depends on the encoding strategy that you have been using to obtain this vector. Roughly speaking, the vectors associated with each object have some sort of context that have been affected by the other objects around. So, I think in your case, using `(batch_size, list_size, object_size)` or `(batch_size, list_size*object_size)` shouldn't make much difference. By using the latter one, you're somehow explicitly inducing to your network that it should take care of context when classifying the instances.